# Add space within foreach elements

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, foreach

i have two foreach operations nested like below.

```
@foreach (var post in Model.Posts)
  {
     <article class="post-@post.PostId @post.PostType sticky post-item isotope-item 
     @foreach (var category in post.Categories)
     {
       @category.FormattedCategoryName
     }">
  }
```

Here's a sample of the output data:

```
<article class="post-1024 format-standard sticky post-item isotope-item cat1cat2cat3cat4cat5" style="width: 429px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate3d(2px, 1px, 0px);">
```

The only thing wrong is I could not separate @category.FormattedCategoryName with blank spaces. It might be an easy string operation but how? Any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you trying to add "cat1", "cat2', etc as class names?

Comment: Outputting a single space? Seems trivial, what's the issue?

Comment: They're just categories. I just need them like "technology food travelling soccer". I need to seperate them one another with space .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below instead:

```
@category.FormattedCategoryName<text>&nbsp;</text>
```

Or Alternately

```
@Html.Raw(string.Contact(category.FormattedCategoryName, "&nbsp;"))
```

**Edit:**

As per the @freedomn-m comment the proposed solution should be replace the foreach loop with below:

```
@string.Join(" ",  post.Categories.Select(c => c.FormattedCategoryName).ToArray())
```

So overall structure would be:

```
<article class="post-@post.PostId @post.PostType sticky post-item isotope-item 
    @string.Join(" ",  post.Categories.Select(c => c.FormattedCategoryName).ToArray())">
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: While this would work for html, it won't work for an element attribute - in this case the class name would be 'cat1&nbsp;cat2' the second would work with just simple " "

Comment: I missed that it needed a sub property of Categories - so your updated answer with `string.Join` matches what my answer should have been.